# How to Rotate and Animate object every other angle?

Tags: animation

I am trying to create an animation by rotating an object every 137.5 degrees on its origin (at 550 RPM with 24 frames/sec) and taking those frames to create a video.

How would I implement this?

Answer (score 1):

**Driver Approach**

You can type a driver directly into field using #.  Typing

```
#radians(137.5 * frame)
```

into the rotation.z field of an object will make it spin at 550rpm at 24 fps.

In the added file I've set up two custom properties "spin", how many degrees per frame, and "rpm".

[image]

The rotor rotates

```
radians(spin * frame)
```

and the rpm is calculated via a driver by

```
rpm = fps * spin * 60/360
```

[image]

Original post: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?229688-Helicopter-Rotor&p=1937512&viewfull=1#post1937512